# How to determine the number of steps on a nested for loop?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, math

I've been working on this algorithm question for a while now and haven't made much progress. The given code is

```
for(i = n; i > 0; i = i-4){
  for(j = i; j < n; j++){
  ...
  }
}
```

The goal is to determine the theta-runtime of the nested loop. My main issue came when trying to write out the values of i at each iteration. I figured on the first iteration i=n, then on the second iteration it will be i=n-4, and then i=n-8 and so on, but I get confused in determining what the last value of i should be(and more importantly, what the last iteration of the outerloop would be). I spoke with a friend who suggested that the total number of outerloop iterations should be the ceiling of n/4, which seems to make sense, but I don't know how to verify that. Does anyone have any idea how to approach this kind of problem?

Comment: Before looking at the inner loop, it's worth observing that the outer loop doesn't terminate for positive n.  It looks like the inner loop doesn't iterate at all, for any value of n.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the code,  the `i` variable on the second iteration of the outer loop will be `n+4`, not `n-4`.

Comment: @danh I wonder what could prevent the inner loop from iterating....?

Comment: @CiaPan, the terminal condition in the inner loop is j<n.  j is always >= i, and I is always >= n, therefore j is always >= n

Comment: Whoops, just noticed the OP edited to decrease i

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you wanted to decrease the value of 'i' by 4 in every iteration.

But instead of decreasing, you're increasing it.

Try like following

```
for(i = n; i > 0; i = i-4){
  for(j = i; j < n; j++){
  ...
  }
}
```

"total number of outerloop iterations should be the ceiling of n/4" - it's true. As you're decreasing the value of 'i' by 4.

Think about it like this, when you're decreasing the value by 1, it'll run for 'n' times. When you'll decrease by 2, it'll run for n / 2 times. And so on...

To verify the answer, you can keep a counter in your code, then print the value of the count at the end of the program.

About determining the last of 'i':

The last value of 'i' will be from 1 to 4 for which your code will get into the inner loop. (because you're running the loop as long as **i > 0** ).

```
int outerLoopCount = 0;
for( i = n; i > 0; i = i-4)
{
    outerLoopCount++;
    for(j = i; j < n; j++)
    {
        
    }
}
printf("outer loop count: %d\n", outerLoopCount);
```

Comment: just realize that, it was a typo, my mistake, I'll fix it now